# Vuetify - Fixed NavigationDrawer with absolute Footer leaves unnecessary space

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and want the scenario where the `v-navigation-drawer` and the `v-toolbar` are fixed to the view-port but the `v-footer` isn't, i.e only appears once you scroll to the bottom of the page.

I have applied the `fixed` prop to both the drawer and the toolbar and they stick to the view-port just fine. I have also added the `absolute` prop to the footer which makes it appear at the very bottom of the page.

However, even though the footer is not in view, the drawer leaves space at the end that a 'fixed' footer would have taken up, which doesn't look right.

Screenshot:
[image]

When I scroll to the bottom, the footer takes up the space that was left for it:
[image]

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 16):

It's hacky, but I fixed it by adding `app` & `inset` and removing the left padding with `.pl-0` like this:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
      v-model='state.drawerOpen'
      fixed
      app >

    <v-list >

    </v-list>

    <v-footer class="justify-center pl-0" inset app>
      <span>&copy; 2018</span>
    </v-footer> 

</v-navigation-drawer>
```

#### [Demo in CodePen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/wQxxWZ)

Answer (score 3):

```
[Bug Report] v-footer leaves v-navigation-drawer too short when inset #4686
```

See this github [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4686), I believe you have found a bug that has been tagged `critical` and `inProgress` 14 days ago. [Here](https://codepen.io/a-riva/pen/OwpPOg) is a codepen demo of the bug.